# Extend Joi with a custom type for populated strings

Tags: javascript, hapi.js, joi

I want to create a custom Joi type for `populatedString`s by using `.extend(..)` to create a type based on `joi.string()` which:

- Trims the string
- Changes the value to `undefined` if the `trimmed string === ''` so the validated output won't contain the key at all
- Overrides `.required()` so it acts on the trimmed string and creates errors using my own language. When .required() is set on my type it means that it requires a string which does not only contain white space or is empty

My attempt so far which is close:

```
    const StandardJoi = require("joi");

    const Joi = StandardJoi.extend(joi => ({
      base: joi.string(),
      name: "populatedString",
      language: {
        required: "needs to be a a string containing non whitespace characters"
      },
      pre(value, state, options) {
        value = value.trim();
        return value === "" ? undefined : value;
      },
      rules: [
        {
          name: "required",
          validate(params, value, state, options) {
            if (value === undefined) {
              return this.createError(
                "populatedString.required",
                { v: value },
                state,
                options
              );
            }

            return value;
          }
        }
      ]
    }));
```

Examples of it working

```
    Joi.populatedString().validate(" x "); // $.value === 'x'
    Joi.populatedString().validate("  "); // $.value === undefined

    // $.error.details
    //
    // [ { message: '"value" needs to be a a string containing non whitespace characters',​​​​​
    // ​​​​​    path: [],​​​​​
    // ​​​​​    type: 'populatedString.required',​​​​​
    // ​​​​​    context: { v: undefined, key: undefined, label: 'value' } } ]​​​​​
    Joi.populatedString()
      .required()
      .validate("  ");

    // $.value
    //
    // { inObj1: 'o' }
    Joi.object()
      .keys({
        inObj1: Joi.populatedString()
      })
      .validate({ inObj1: " o " });
```

But it does not fail (as it should) for

```
    // ​​​​​{ error: null, value: {}, then: [λ: then], catch: [λ: catch] }​​​​​
    Joi.object()
      .keys({
        inObj2: Joi.populatedString(),
        inObj3: Joi.populatedString().required()
      })
      .validate({ inObj2: "  " });
```

Even though `inObj3` is `.required()` and not supplied it doesn't fail.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it:

```
    const BaseJoi = require("joi");

    const Joi = BaseJoi.extend(joi => ({
      base: joi.string(),
      name: "populatedString",
      language: {
        required: "needs to be a a string containing non whitespace characters"
      },
      pre(value, state, options) {
        value = value.trim();
        return value === "" ? undefined : value;
      },
      rules: [
        {
          name: "required",
          setup(params) {
            return this.options({ presence: "required" });
          },
          validate(params, value, state, options) {
            if (value === undefined) {
              return this.createError(
                "populatedString.required",
                { v: value },
                state,
                options
              );
            }

            return value;
          }
        }
      ]
    }));
```

The fix was to add `setup` and let it set the option `presence = required` if `required()` was called.